# How to replace a single similar line only AFTER a match

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to search for a specific item `[7_addons]` and ONLY replace the NEXT entry that appears from `enabled=0` to `enabled=1`.

in this example:

```
sed -i -e 's#enabled=0#enabled=1#g' /etc/file.txt
```

..replaces EVERYTHING showing `enabled=0` in `file.txt`, but I ONLY want it to replace what comes next after the search string `7_addons`, replace `=0` with `=1`, then STOP.

Comment: What does your data look like and what do you want it to look like after your modification? Update the question, don't add comments.

Comment: It is a file with repository info - after each repository definition, the last line in that section contains the line:

enabled=0

So each repository section in the file has its own tag, in brackets ie.[ol7_addons]

I was sed to search for the tag, then ONLY modify the next occurance of enabled=0 and change it to enabled=1.

(Note, its easy to do enabled=0 for everything in the file, but I dont want everything enabled, just the next line that appears like that after the matcher)

Comment: It is a file with repository info divided by sections - after each repository definition section, the last line in that section contains the line:

enabled=0

Basically each repository section in the file has its own tag, in brackets ie.[ol7_addons]

I wanted sed to search for the tag, then ONLY modify the next occurrence of enabled=0 and change it to enabled=1.

(Note, its easy to do enabled=0 for everything in the file, but I dont want everything enabled, just the next line that appears like that after the matcher)

Comment: Please update the question with a properly formatted example.

Comment: So what we need is a sample of maybe 10+ lines copied and pasted from your sample file into the question (exactly as they appear in the question). Also, type out an example of the output you'd like returned with relation to the example.

Comment: By "only replace the next entry" do you mean "only replace the next _enabled_ line" or do you mean "replace the enabled line in the next `[_addons]` *stanza*"?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace the assumed-exist `enabled` line that follows the first `[7_addons]` line in the file, you could use ed!

```
ed -s input <<< $'/^\[7_addons\]$\n/^enabled=0\nc\nenabled=1\n.\nw\nq' > /dev/null
```

Starting from the outside in, this executes `ed` in script mode on the `input` file and passes it an ANSI quoted string as a here-string, then redirects the output to /dev/null. The /dev/null redirection simply discards ed's reporting of the lines that it finds while doing the work.

The here-string breaks down to the following `\n`-separated commands:

1. `/^\[7_addons\]$` -- search forwards for the line that is exactly `[7_addons]` (being anchored to the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the line
2. `/^enabled=0$` -- *then* search forwards for the line that is exactly `enabled=0`
3. `c` -- change that line
4. `enabled=1` -- to this text
5. `.` -- end the replacement text
6. `w` -- write the file to disk
7. `q` -- quit ed

On this sample input:

```
[1_addons]
enabled=0
foo=bar
[7_addons]
foo=baz
enabled=0
other=bat
[8_addons]
foo=quux
```

The resulting file is:

```
[1_addons]
enabled=0
foo=bar
[7_addons]
foo=baz
enabled=1
other=bat
[8_addons]
foo=quux
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/\[7_addons\]/{n;s/enabled=0/enabled=1/}'
```

Or if there are other lines between `[7_addons]` and `enabled=0`:

```
sed '/\[7_addons\]/,/enabled=/s/enabled=0/enabled=1/'
```

Example:

```
$ cat foo
[2_foo]
enabled=0
[7_addons]
extra fluff
enabled=0
enabled=0
$ sed '/\[7_addons\]/,/enabled=/s/enabled=0/enabled=1/' foo
[2_foo]
enabled=0
[7_addons]
extra fluff
enabled=1
enabled=0
```

You may want to make the regexp a bit more strict; I cannot do that, based on the data from your question.

Comment: This would work _if_ the `enabled=0` was on the very next line after `[7_addons]`, but not if it came later.  This is why I asked the user to add a real example to the question. His description of the data is ambiguous.

Comment: If they add an example where this answer doesn't apply, I'll remove the answer (tomorrow morning).

Comment: Your 2nd solution won't work if there's another`enabled=` (e.g. `enabled=1`) line _before_ the 1st `enabled=0` that follows after the `[7_addons]` (which is highly unlikely I know...). Use a more strict range to take care of that: `sed '/\[7_addons\]/,/enabled=0/s/enabled=0/enabled=1/'`

Comment: @don_crissti that was intended -- if  `[7_addons]` is already followed by `enabled=1`, don't set to 1 an `enabled=0` from from the next `[section]`. That would still wreak havoc if the `[7_addons]` section didn't have any `enabled` key whatsoever -- I'll assume that could not happen and leave it as is.

Comment: Yes, that's also true. Come to think, the best way to solve the problem here is to use a tool designed to process `INI` files.

Comment: [ol7_addons]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever Add ons ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/addons/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0


[ol7_other]
name=Oracle Linux $releasever other ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/other/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0

Comment: @AndrewJ, it's nearly impossible to read formatted data in comments; please use the [edit link for your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/493093/edit) to update it in response to the requests here and on the main question. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewJ assuming that your `[section]` and `key=value` from your comment are on separate lines, my 2nd example should work, provided that you replace `\[7_addons\]` with `\[ol7_addons\]`